# Need help showing my example does (or doesn't) work.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find an example of when $(A \bigcup B)^\circ \supset A^\circ \bigcup B^\circ$. Where $^\circ$ denotes the interior of a set. It has been previously shown in [the text](http://web.pdx.edu/~erdman/PTAC/problemtext_pdf.pdf) that:

> The interior of the set $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers is empty.

My intuition is telling me that $(\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q} \bigcup \mathbb{Q})^\circ \supset (\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})^\circ \bigcup \mathbb{Q}^\circ$. Since, $(\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q} \bigcup \mathbb{Q})^\circ = \mathbb{R} = (-\infty, \infty)$, but I don't exactly know what the size of $(\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})^\circ \bigcup \mathbb{Q}^\circ$ is, all I can think of reducing it down to:

$$(\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})^\circ \bigcup \emptyset$$
$$(\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})^\circ$$

Is there a way I can show $\mathbb{R}^\circ \supset (\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})^\circ$? Is it even true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $A=\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ and $B=\mathbb Q$. Then $A^\circ =B^\circ=\emptyset$, but $A\cup B= \mathbb R$ so $(A\cup B)^\circ =\mathbb R$.

To show that $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ has empty interior, assume that it doesn't, so there exists an interval $(a,b)$ contained in $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$. But every interval contains rationals, which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: That's what the OP wanted to do, but didn't know that $A^\circ=\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I guess I am trying to think *why* there must exist a rational in every interval. It just kind of confuses me since the density of irrational numbers is greater than rational numbers I have a hard time conceiving that *every* interval must contain at least one rational given there are more irrational numbers. Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: That's equivalent to asking why there must be a rational number between distinct irrational numbers.  You can argue that from Dedekind cuts (in that construction of the reals).  If $a < b$ are irrational numbers, suppose there is no rational $a < p < b$.  But then $a$ and $b$ would be the same Dedekind cut, giving $a = b$, a contradiction.

Comment: @grantfgates: I haven't covered Dedekind cuts, but I guess that means I'll get to it eventually, so I'll look into it and see if I can understand it, if not, I'll just wait for later I guess and for now accept it's true then. Thanks!

Comment: Another way to define the reals is to take the completion of the rationals. You first start with the natural numbers, then you take fractions of them so you have the rationals. Next, you define the real numbers to be essentially the limits of the rationals (more accurately, the reals are the completion of the metric space of rationals). Therefore, using this definition, the rationals are arbitrarily close to any real, so in particular any interval will contain a lot of them!

Answer (score 0):

Any nonempty open interval in $\mathbb R$ contains both rational and irrational points. Therefore the set of irrationals has no interior points either.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if you can, would you please look at my other comment to Dimitrios's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with the [Cantor Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), another example that would work would be:

> Let $A$ be the Cantor set, and $B = [0, 1] \setminus A$, so that $B$ is the union of the intervals removed from $[0, 1]$ in the construction of $A$.  Then $B$ is open, so $B^\circ = B$.  But $A$ has empty interior, so that $A^\circ \cup B^\circ = B$.  However, $(A\cup B)^\circ = (0, 1) \supset B$.

Letting $A$ be any closed nowhere dense set and $B$ its complement would work similarly.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Cantor Set, but I will look into it. Thank you for the answer.